# Oracle replication of fast changing table

Tags: oracle, triggers, stream, materialized-views, replicate

I have two oracle 11g databases: production and backup where some data is replicated via MQ mechanism for the rest I stil need a solution. 
Basically, what I need is way of synchronously replication for a column in a table that is updating very fast on production database. Replication must be instanteniously so in case production database goes down all that information (that column) to be ready and updated on backup. That's on one hand. On the other hand performace shouldn't be alterated on production during the replication. The table could have hundreds of thousands of rows, not all of them should be replicated (there are data IN and data OUT - only for data OUT I need that column replicated on backup).
I was thinking to materialized view, triggers and streams.
For triggers things are ... easy but some people say it's not a recomended way. I did a db link and a trigger like that:

```
after update of column
for each row
update table@backup set column = :NEW.column...
```

For materialized view... I don't have yet in mind a solution as I don't know how to actualy update in my backup.table only the last row updated on production.table using the records from materializedview.

For streams.. I'm not familiar with these and I really don't know if I could replicate only changes on a column or, better, replicate entire table and then, on backup, execute some select etc etc.

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot

Comment: If "synchronous" really means synchronous, that implies that you need the overhead of doing a two-phase commit across the databases before a transaction can complete on the primary.  That goes against your desire to have no impact on performance on the primary.  You can minimize impact on the primary if you're willing to replicate the data asynchronously and accept that there is a potential for the replica to be a few seconds behind the primary.  Your two requirements are at odds-- which one wins?

Comment: Thanks for your input. Hard to decide. I would like to have synchronous replication and minimum impact on performance. In the primary database a lot of things are happening - I only need that column update to replicate on the backup site. Of course this should be tested and, together with the client, decide for go/no-go.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need combination of Oracle Streams and possibly Change Data Capture. Also note that Oracle is moving towards deprecating Streams and is encouraging future users to move to Goldengate. See here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17642/deprecated.htm#BABEAJJE

So here are the requirements that I see that I can understand:

1. 100% infallible data replication.
2. No performance impact on source.

Neither of these are achievable independently much less both of them together. Replication of any sort will always have a delay between systems based on source and target system load, IO, CPU, network traffic and latency, DB commits, all of these other things. And yes I am mixing up layers in those items, not all of them are "apples to apples" but the point is that a lot of things have to happen to do replication.

I am also a bit confused on how you would fail over to this secondary database system if the primary goes down? Are you planning to allow writes to secondary if primary is down? Is your application smart enough to detect the failure of the primary? If the real business requirement is "application must have 99.9% (or whatever percentage) of availability I am not sure that replication is the answer for what you want.

Here is what you can do:

1. Get your management/business users to define what level of downtime is acceptable. If they say "none!" then go to #2, sometimes people ask for perfection without inquiring as to the infinite cost.
2. Put together several options in a presentation and say something along the lines of the following:

"For UNPLANNED downtime of 99.9%, which is downtime of 45 minutes a month (31*24*60*.001) that takes 24 hours to recover from a disaster, and loses up to the last say hour of data in a worst case scenario then we can run a stand-alone Oracle server, have backup hardware on hand, and it will cost X dollars/euros/whatever. Oh and here is what the staffing costs break out to as well.

For 99.99% we need a second server we do regular backup restores to, etc., and it will cost 5X

For 99.999% we need replication, multiple masters, updates to our software application, a higher level of testing, more staff, etc., and it will cost 10X or 20X or something."

I've purely made up all of these numbers and scenarios but you can see how it works. When people are confronted with how much it costs to really do this stuff -- and the cost of MAINTAINING IT -- then they often change their minds.

I am trying to see if replication is **really** necessary for you first before getting into all of the costly and painful details. I've worked on replicated systems before and I will warn you that although they are supposed to increase uptime, replication with Streams and CDC is pretty complicated and often creates a whole other set of failure modes.

Comment: GoldenGate isn't something you need to pay for? I need 0(zero) RPO - that means RTO couldn't be 0 - depending on the moment of the day it could be one hour or even more. Application is not a smart one, instead some manual jobs must be done, there are other systems to compare with (also manually) and only after these checks the backup app can be started - it only needs 100% (99.999%) correct business data.
That column updates I need to bring from production using Oracle methods. It is updated at a high speed and in business critical moments so replication must be done with minimum impact.

Comment: I believe Goldengate does require additional licensing fees where Streams comes bundled with Oracle although I wasn't able to find anything with a quick Google search. Here are a couple more articles giving some good info about Streams vs. Goldengate from a technical perspective: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3921851/Oracle-Database-Replication-Streams-vs-GoldenGate.htm and http://blog.mdbbi.com/post/43533069697/first-impressions-oracle-goldengate-vs

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests with triggers and I'm concerned because in case of a connectivity problem between those 2 databases, that trigger will 'stop' any insert into the  main database until connectivity is re-established. This can be solved using a stored procedure like here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Example
AFTER INSERT ON Emp_tab
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   Insert_row_proc;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Insert_row_proc AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Emp_tab@Remote
    VALUES ('x');
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
       INSERT INTO Emp_log
       VALUES ('x');
END;
```

Stil, my question is: should I trust this trigger or go for streams (again, I don't know yet if I could replicate only one column using streams)
Thanks